# postgresql date to timestamp conversion unexpected hours

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to convert date field into timestamp with timezone field...

```
UPDATE table SET timestamp_field=date_field AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
```

but there are two different result. If I run it as user, which has timezone set to Europe/Warsaw' - the result is e.g. `2023-03-20 00:00:00+01` Which is correct

but if i run it as user, which has timezone set to UTC the result is:
`2023-03-20 02:00:00+01` which is wrong...sorry - which is not what I want :D

How to make UPDATE to be user timezone independent?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid, but works:

before update execute:

```
SET timezone = 'Europe/Warsaw';
```